# Stripe create customer iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe and parse to allow the user of my app to enter in their credit card and purchase. I got that far the user can make a purchase everything is good. But I want to allow the user to enter their CC information and have that save so they don't have to keep re-entering it. I'm having a really hard time doing this I got the first part all figured out I just need to get this.

**Update**:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    if (![self.paymentView isValid]) {
        return;
    }
    if (![Stripe defaultPublishableKey]) {
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Publishable Key"
                                                          message:@"Please specify a Stripe Publishable Key in Constants.m"
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK")
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];
        return;
    }
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    STPCard *card = [[STPCard alloc] init];
    card.number = self.paymentView.card.number;
    card.expMonth = self.paymentView.card.expMonth;
    card.expYear = self.paymentView.card.expYear;
    card.cvc = self.paymentView.card.cvc;
    [Stripe createTokenWithCard:card completion:^(STPToken *token, NSError *error) {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        if (error) {
            [self hasError:error];
        } else {
           [self createCustomerFromCard:(NSString *)token completion:(PFIdResultBlock)handler]; //I'm having trouble on this line here.
        }
    }];
}
- (void)hasError:(NSError *)error {
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"Error")
                                                      message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK")
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
}

+ (void)createCustomerFromCard:(NSString *)token completion:(PFIdResultBlock)handler
{
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"createCustomer"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"tokenId":token,
                                        }
                                block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
                                    //Object is an NSDictionary that contains the stripe customer information, you can use this as is, or create an instance of your own customer class
                                    handler(object,error);
                                }];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1 Generate a Customer using Parse's API.

Step 2 Generate a Token from the CC information they enter again using Parse's API. If you need help with this, and the cloud code required let me know.

Step 3 Add a CC to a customer. I have the code below. The response back will be a Dictionary, and then I create an STPCard from the dictionary.

iOS Code:

```
typedef void (^STPCardCompletionBlock)(STPCard *card,NSError *error);

    +(void)addTokenId:(NSString *)tokenId toCustomerId:(NSString *)customerId completion:(STPCardCompletionBlock)handler
{
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"stripeUpdateCustomer" withParameters:@{@"customerId":customerId,@"data":@{@"card":tokenId}} block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
        handler([[STPCard alloc]initWithAttributeDictionary:object],error);
    }];
}
```

Cloud Code Required:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("stripeUpdateCustomer", function(request, response) 
{
        Stripe.Customers.update
    (
        request.params["customerId"],
        request.params["data"],
        {
            success:function(results)
            {
                console.log(results["id"]);
                response.success(results);
            },
            error:function(error)
            {
                response.error("Error:" +error); 
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Here I have implemented jflinter's cloud code. Keep in mind you can include a lot more than just the tokenId to create a customer, like email, description, metadata, etc. but this just creates a customer with a card, and no other information:

```
+(void)createCustomerFromCard:(NSString *)tokenId completion:(PFIdResultBlock)handler
{
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"createCustomer"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"tokenId":tokenId,
                                        }
                                block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
                                    //Object is an NSDictionary that contains the stripe customer information, you can use this as is, or create an instance of your own customer class
                                    handler(object,error);
    }];
}
```

Creating a charge using jflinter's code:

```
+(void)chargeCustomer:(NSString *)customerId amount:(NSNumber *)amountInCents completion:(PFIdResultBlock)handler
{
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"chargeCustomer"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"amount":amountInCents,
                                        @"customerId":customerId
                                        }
                                block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
                                    //Object is an NSDictionary that contains the stripe charge information, you can use this as is or create, an instance of your own charge class.
                                    handler(object,error);

                                }];
}
@end
```

Comment: hey thanks for the post I will try this when I get home. I actually got the code I posted above from you :) I'll let you how it turns out. Thanks!

Comment: I don't really use Parse's stripe module as it is very limited in it's capabilities. If you want to simply create a token, and charge a card it gets the job done though.

Comment: I already have it that the user can purchase something but I would like to save their cc info and use it later.

Comment: @hybrdthy911 I coppied the iOS portion of your code and I get: No visible (at)interface for "ViewController" declares the selector 'addTokenId:' I will update the question with my code. Thanks!

Comment: When calling the method you forgot the rest of the method  "toCustomerId:(NSString *)customerId completion:(STPCardCompletionBlock)handler"

Do you need help creating the customer as well? I thought you already had created a customer, and wanted to add the card and charge it.

Comment: I actually need to create the customer I have an idea on the backend but I'm lost on the front end.

Comment: I updated my answer with some ios code for customer creation, and charging, I just used jflinter's cloud code. I also listed my github for my ios stripe library. My library does not use parse's stripe modules though, so it will look quite a bit different.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply I'm still having uses however. In my if statement I'm trying to go to the create user method if the token was successfully created, but I can't get it to work. I update my question with the code. Could you take a look and get back to me? Thanks!

Comment: You must use the tokenId, but you are trying to pass the entire token. pass token.tokenId

Comment: Like this? [self createCustomerFromCard:tokenId]; When I do that I get an ARC Semantic Issue.

Comment: You can't use self, it is a class method, not an instance method. So if your class is PaymentViewController for examples, you must execute it using [PaymentViewController createCustomerFromCard:token.tokenId completion:^(id object, NSError *error) {
        
    }]

Comment: Ok thank you so much! Did everything you said and now I am successfully able to save a customer and make purchases from that customer! Thanks again I apologies for my noobish questions!

Answer (score 11):

So, you're doing everything right on the iOS side of things. The difference is that on your backend, you're going to want to make a `Customer` out of this token and then make charges against that `Customer`. There is a highly-relevant section on this in our documentation at https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later.

If I were doing this, I'd create 2 Parse functions: one called `createCustomer`, which would take a `tokenId`, create a `Customer` with it, and return that customer's ID. You could call this in your iOS app, and then persist the customer ID locally. (You could also attach it to your `User` on the Parse backend. The important thing is just that you want to be able to retrieve it later). When your app user creates a token by entering their card info, you'd call this function once.

Then, any future time you want to make another charge against that credit card, you'd call a second Parse function, call it `chargeCustomer`. This would take the customerId that you saved previously and an amount (and, optionally, currency, etc). That's it!

Here's what those functions might look like (please note, I haven't tested this code, so there may be small errors, but it should be enough to communicate my point):

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createCustomer", function(request, response) {
  Stripe.Customers.create({
    card: request.params['tokenId']
  }, {
    success: function(customer) {
      response.success(customer.id);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error("Error:" +error); 
    }
  })
});

Parse.Cloud.define("chargeCustomer", function(request, response) {
  Stripe.Charges.create({
    amount: request.params['amount'],
    currency: "usd",
    customer: request.params['customerId']
  }, {
    success: function(customer) {
      response.success(charge.id);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error("Error:" +error); 
    }
  })
});
```

Hopefully that helps. If you need further assistance, feel free to contact support@stripe.com.

Jack

Comment: Thanks for the post, the part I'm having trouble with is actually the iOS portion I got the cloud code part all figured out. I'm still having trouble creating the customer on the iOS side. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Correction on @jflinter 's code above.  On the chargeCustomer function. replace function(**customer**) with function (**charge**)

```
Parse.Cloud.define("chargeCustomer", function(request, response) {
  Stripe.Charges.create({
    amount: request.params['amount'],
    currency: "usd",
    customer: request.params['customerId']
  }, {
    success: function(charge) {
      response.success(charge.id);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error("Error:" +error); 
    }
  })
});
```